# Image doesn't load to iphone when compiling a project from xcode 4 to the device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, sdk, xcode4

I am trying to build a project onto my iphone from Xcode 4, which has an image, and from some reason I am getting an error that the file is missing or that it is not a .png, even though it is. the project compiles and runs on my device fine, just without the image. when i run it on the computer, the image loads properly.

any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the filename of the image. The device uses a case sensitive file system, the simulator usually runs on a case insensitive file system.

So `image.PNG` and `Image.png` reference the same file on the simulator, but different files on the actual device.